# Is it possible to load more than 50 results in Backoffice search?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We are currently want to load more than the default 50 elements per page into the backoffice search results. This was possible using the old HMC interface. There was a dropdown to select the number of results. Is there a similar fuctionality in the SAP Commerce Backoffice Interface?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, simply add this property with the corresponding value you want :

```
hmc.result.ranges.default
```